# Looping and Searching in Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I need to loop over a numpy array and then do the following search. The following is taking almost 60(s) for an array (npArray1 and npArray2 in the example below) with around 300K values.

In other words, I am  looking for the index of the first occurence in npArray2 
for every value of npArray1.

```
for id in np.nditer(npArray1):                    
       newId=(np.where(npArray2==id))[0][0]
```

Is there anyway I can make the above faster using numpy? I need to run the script above on much bigger arrays (50M). Please note that my two numpy arrays in the lines above, npArray1 and npArray2  are not necessarily the same size, but they are both 1d.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: Could you add some short and complete code example? Define two arrays, etc.. It would help people to understand better your problem

Comment: Curious if any of the solutions posted here work for you?

Answer (score 1):

The function [np.unique](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) will do much of the work for you:

```
npArray2 = np.random.randint(100,None,(1000,)) #1000-long vector of ints between 1 and 100, so lots of repeats
vals,idxs = np.unique(searchMe, return_index=True) #each unique value AND the index of its first appearance
for val in npArray1:
  newId = idxs[vals==val][0]
```

`vals` is an array containing the unique values in `npArray2`, while `idxs` gives the index of the first appearance of each value in `npArray2`. Searching in `vals` should be much faster than in `npArray1` because it's smaller.

You can speed up the search further by taking advantage of the fact that `vals` is sorted:

```
import bisect  #we can use binary search since vals is sorted
for val in npArray1:
    newId = idxs[bisect.bisect_left(vals, val)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input arrays contain unique values, you can use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) with its optional `sorter` option for a vectorized solution, like so -

```
arr2_sortidx = npArray2.argsort()
idx = np.searchsorted(npArray2,npArray1,sorter=arr2_sortidx)
out1 = arr2_sortidx[idx]
```

Sample run to verify output -

```
In [154]: npArray1
Out[154]: array([77, 19,  0, 69])

In [155]: npArray2
Out[155]: array([ 8, 33, 12, 19, 77, 30, 81, 69, 20,  0])

In [156]: out = np.empty(npArray1.size,dtype=int)
     ...: for i,id in np.ndenumerate(npArray1):
     ...:     out[i] = (np.where(npArray2==id))[0][0]
     ...:     

In [157]: arr2_sortidx = npArray2.argsort()
     ...: idx = np.searchsorted(npArray2,npArray1,sorter=arr2_sortidx)
     ...: out1 = arr2_sortidx[idx]
     ...: 

In [158]: out
Out[158]: array([4, 3, 9, 7])

In [159]: out1
Out[159]: array([4, 3, 9, 7])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [175]: def original_app(npArray1,npArray2):
     ...:     out = np.empty(npArray1.size,dtype=int)
     ...:     for i,id in np.ndenumerate(npArray1):
     ...:         out[i] = (np.where(npArray2==id))[0][0] 
     ...:     return out
     ...: 
     ...: def searchsorted_app(npArray1,npArray2):
     ...:   arr2_sortidx = npArray2.argsort()
     ...:   idx = np.searchsorted(npArray2,npArray1,sorter=arr2_sortidx)
     ...:   return arr2_sortidx[idx]
     ...: 

In [176]: # Setup inputs
     ...: M,N = 50000,40000 # npArray2 and npArray1 sizes respectively
     ...: maxn = 200000
     ...: npArray2 = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,maxn,(M)))
     ...: npArray2 = npArray2[np.random.permutation(npArray2.size)]
     ...: npArray1 = npArray2[np.random.permutation(npArray2.size)[:N]]
     ...: 

In [177]: out1 = original_app(npArray1,npArray2)

In [178]: out2 = searchsorted_app(npArray1,npArray2)

In [179]: np.allclose(out1,out2)
Out[179]: True

In [180]: %timeit original_app(npArray1,npArray2)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.14 s per loop

In [181]: %timeit searchsorted_app(npArray1,npArray2)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: Really great answer. Though sorting a large array might be quite time and CPU consuming. In every other aspect you solution is just elegant and simple.

Comment: @RomanKh Thanks! I need to get into `numba` at some point too! Lovely blog on `numba` you got there!

Answer (score 0):

In the task you specified you have to iterate over the array one way or another. So you can just think of a considerable performance improvement without changing your algorithm too much. This is where `numba` might be of a great help:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit
def numba_iter(npa1, npa2):
    for id in np.nditer(npa1):                    
        newId=(np.where(npa2==id))[0][0]
```

This simple approach might make your program much faster. Look at some examples and benchmarks [here](http://roman-kh.github.io/numba-1/).